# TestNG priority annotation not working when non-sequential priorities

Tags: testing, annotations, testng

I'm having some problems with the Priority annotation in TestNG not running test cases.  My priority numbers are not sequential, I have intentionally skipped numbers so at a future date I can add some test methods between them so the run in a specific order.  Any ideas how I can get TestNG to execute my test methods that follow the number gap? For example, I have priorities in the order of 1 - 3 and then I jump to 200 - 202.  The tests with priorities 200 - 202 are not being executed.  Thanks for your time.

```
public class ClassOneTest{
    @Test (enabled=true, priority=1)
    public void methodOneTest() {
        .....
    }

    /**
     * Updates the ServiceNow End Point
     */
    @Test (enabled=true, priority=2)
    public void methodTwoTest() {
        .....
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the ServiceNow End Point
     */
    @Test (enabled=true, priority=3)
    public void methodTwoTest() {
        .....
    }
}

public class ClassTwoTest{
    @Test (enabled=true, priority=200)
    public void methodThreeTest() {
        .....
    }

    /**
     * Updates the ServiceNow End Point
     */
    @Test (enabled=true, priority=201)
    public void methodFourTest() {
        .....
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the ServiceNow End Point
     */
    @Test (enabled=true, priority=202)
    public void methodFiveTest() {
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The class with the priorities in the 200's was being loaded in the suite before the class with the lower priorities.  Once I changed the loading order it worked fine.